# How to extract List from List<List> in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to extract the 2nd field of all the lists that I have

Example :

```
List<List> data = [
    [11L, x.id, "12467"],
    [12L, y.id, "12467"],
    [13L, z.id, "12467"],
]
```

the result would be

```
[x.id, y.id, z.id]
```

Do I have to iterate or groovy has a faster and better way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
List<List> data = [
   [11L, x.id, "12467"],
   [12L, y.id, "12467"],
   [13L, z.id, "12467"],
]

def fields = data.collect { it[1] }
assert fields == ['x.id', 'y.id', 'z.id']
```

Mind that it will work if and only if the order of each list in `data` collection will be the same.

Comment: another option: `data*.get(1)`